# Sorting list in a specific order

Tags: java, collections

I have a list as below

(2D, 1D, 1Y, 12W, 1W, 23M, 4M, 2Y, 12D)

I want to sort in the following order

1. by the letters (D,W,M,Y)
2. then numerically

So I should have output

(1D, 2D, 12D, 1W, 12W, 4M, 23M, 1Y, 2Y)

I have tried this

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  List<String> listNew = new ArrayList<>();
  listNew.add("2D");
  listNew.add("1D");
  listNew.add("1Y");
  listNew.add("12W");
  listNew.add("1W");
  listNew.add("23M");
  listNew.add("4M");
  listNew.add("2Y");
  listNew.add("12D");
  listNew.add("1W");
  List<String> order = Arrays.asList("D", "W", "M","Y");
  listNew.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(((String) s).substring(0, ((String) s).length() - 1))).thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(order::indexOf)));
  for (String element : listNew) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

}

However I get this output:

1D
1Y
1W
1W
2D
2Y
4M
12W
12D
23M

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are these time units like days, weeks, months and years? If so, should not 12 days come after 1 week?

Answer (score 3):

First, you should sort by the index in `order`, then by the numeric value.

Moreover, you should get the index of the last character in the string in `order`, instead of passing the whole `String` to `indexOf`.

```java
var order = Arrays.asList('D', 'W', 'M','Y'); // use chars instead of String
listNew.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> order.indexOf(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)))
             .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 0, s.length() - 1, 10)));
```

Comment: Note that you [don’t need `substring` for parsing a part of a string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,int)) since Java 9, i.e. `Integer.parseInt(s, 0, s.length() - 1, 10)` for this use case.

Comment: @Holger Good point. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be just an exercise, so the following might be overkill, but if this is an actual entity it might be worth to create a class/record and define a compare method.

This class would have a number and a period string ('D', 'W', 'M', 'Y'), then to compare them you create two instances and invoke the `compareTo` method:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> listNew = new ArrayList<>();
        listNew.add("2D");
        listNew.add("1D");
        listNew.add("1Y");
        listNew.add("12W");
        listNew.add("1W");
        listNew.add("23M");
        listNew.add("4M");
        listNew.add("2Y");
        listNew.add("12D");
        listNew.add("1W");;
        
        listNew.sort((s, t) -> {
            var a = new TimePeriod(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)), s.substring(s.length() - 1));
            var b = new TimePeriod(Integer.parseInt(t.substring(0, t.length() - 1)), t.substring(t.length() - 1));
            return a.compareTo(b);
        });

        for (String element : listNew) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}

record TimePeriod(int number, String period) {
  private static final List<String> order = Arrays.asList("D", "W", "M", "Y");

  public int compareTo (TimePeriod other){
    int periodPart = Integer.compare( order.indexOf(this.period), order.indexOf(other.period));
    return periodPart != 0 ? periodPart : Integer.compare(this.number, other.number);
  }
}
```

It might not be as clever, but overtime might be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use immutable list, you can use snippet like this:

```java
public static List<String> sort(List<String> data, char... letters) {
    Map<Character, Queue<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String str : data) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(str.charAt(str.length() - 1),
                            PriorityQueue::new)
                .add(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)));
    }

    return IntStream.range(0, letters.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> letters[i])
            .filter(map::containsKey)
            .flatMap((Function<Character, Stream<String>>) ch ->
                    map.get(ch).stream()
                            .map(num -> String.valueOf(num) + ch))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```